# Fastest algo for searching set of characters in given string

Tags: java, algorithm

This is a debate I was having with one of my friends: What would be the fastest way of making a valiation method that checks if the given string has one of the non-allowed characters

Method I:  simple

```
char [] invalidChars = "!@#$%^...".toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
            char ch = myString.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < invalidChars.length; j++) {
                if (invalidChars[j] == ch) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Method II: Exploiting Map's O(1)

```
Map <String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("!", null);
        map.put("@", null);
        map.put("#", null);
        map.put("$", null);
        map.put("^", null);
        ...
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length(); i++) {
            char ch = labels.charAt(i);
            if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

The method I is actually N2 but as good as N when invalidChars are less in number. 
What should be preferred when Case I: There are lots of invalid chars, Case II: only few invalid chars?

Note: I'm not looking for any inbuilt java solutions but, just the algorithm to filter few (not all) non-text characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only interested in validating ASCII characters, then a length-128 boolean lookup-table *may* be faster than either of the above methods.

Comment: Although that could be a solution, it's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @Roy: Why is it not an answer?  It's an O(1) "algorithm", given certain constraints.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've misread, you're right, I've upvoted your comment. I thought he only wanted to know which of the two is faster.

Comment: No, my main purpose is not to reject all non-ascii characters, but to filter few

Comment: @taranfx: I know.  That's not what I'm suggesting!  I'm suggesting you can use an array of booleans, and index into it by the ASCII character value.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, you can always use BitSet, regardless the length

Comment: ahan. this is definitely the fastest but not the cleanest way of writing code. BitSet is a better option.

Comment: @best, @taran: Yes, you're right!  I didn't know about `BitSet` until today!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, overall using big boolean lookup table will be slower (booleans are kept as byte[] in the memory) since it is more way more cache-miss prone than long[]/int[] and bit-twiddling (in that case the table is small enough, though)

Comment: @bestsss: so you're saying it *will* be slower but in this case it might not be.  Hmmm.  I think you're right, somewhere. ;-)

Comment: @Tony, if the boolean[] (which is effectively a byte[]) fits in a cache line, hence always a single load boolean[] could be faster than bit twiddling, otherwise due to the better cache properties long[] is likely to outperform boolean[]. If you now ask why the heck Java doesn't implement boolean[] as long/int[] - b/c the update of a element has to be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple method that would give you `O(n log(m))` time complexity, where `n` is the length of the input and `m` is the number of disallowed characters.

Scan the input one character at a time, and look up the current character in the (sorted) array of disallowed chars using binary search.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a HashSet, which gives you O(1) on add and contains you have:

- O(n) for insertion of each forbidden character
- O(m) for each compare operation

Which leads to O(m+n) where m is the number of forbidden characters and n is the length of the string. But I already see answers which perform better.

But please keep in mind, that most things come with an overhead (like the "hash" in HashSet/HashMap). So even if the asymptotic performance may be better a **naive implementation may be faster** on small inputs. I'm not saying that you should use something that has O(n²) but it may be worth to compare a O(n log n) solution to a O(m) solution for a common set of data!

Answer (score 1):

Fastest!
HashMap is far form the fastest solution, only theoretically it's O(1).

In java: **java.util.BitSet** is designed for your needs. 
Alternatively use self unwrapped long[]/int[] arrays (depending on the target architecture 32/64)

Why HashMap ain't good? The extra luggage coming from accessing and creating buckets is higher than the look up on its right own.

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a hashmap and putting items in there is relatively expensive. However as you've said looking up  items in a hashmap is O(1).

So we have have hashmap fill:  O(n log n) with lookup O(1).

Or the standard way (fill O(1) lookup O(n)).

However since the O(n) lookup happens voor every string the first method in total is O(numberOfInvalidChars + strings*NumberofInValidChars)  the second one is O(numInv log numInv + strings).  Whichs is wayyyy less expensive so almost always cheaper.