# Check if primitive array contains another array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any easy way to check if one array contains another array in Java?

Essentially, I want to do something like this:

```
private static final String NOT_ALLOWED;

public boolean isPasswordOkay(char[] password){
    return new String(password).contains(NOT_ALLOWED);
}
```

...but without converting the password to a `String`, which [Sun indicates could be a security risk](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#PBEEx). Is there a neater method than manually iterating over every element of the array?

Comment: Why is converting the char[] to a String a security risk ? A String contains a char[] within it (it's the implementation)

Comment: @Brian: Strings are a security risk because they copy the char[] and may in memory for an indefinite amount of time (because they may be GCed much later): http://securesoftware.blogspot.com/2009/01/java-security-why-not-to-use-string.html

Comment: Strings are treated specially by the garbage collector and are immutable, so there's no way to ensure that they won't remain in memory after you're finished with them: http://securesoftware.blogspot.com/2009/01/java-security-why-not-to-use-string.html

Comment: @Scott, you are deeply mistaken about GC of the strings. On a side note I guess NOT_ALLOWED contains characters that are not allowed not an entire subsequence, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860336/fastest-algo-for-searching-set-of-characters-in-given-string/4860359#4860359

Comment: @Scott, the only Strings that remain in the memory are the ones you declare like `String xxx= "TehPassWord"` OR you explicitly call `intern()`. There are more cases for the constant pool but they are not interesting, I will read the blog fully and probably it's just wrong if states that strings are treated differently by the GC.

Comment: Unless you are going to zero out the char[] after using it, you haven't achieved anything.  Are you really concerned that someone could get access to the physical memory of your system?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I bet no one even considers the fact that SSLEngine buffers are practically never zero'd. I seriously didn't understand Sun's remark. And the funniest thing is that while they zero the buf, they do nothing about the PushBackInputStream. Cleaning up any bit possible on the way back is just paranoid, hard to implement and requires YOU to implement virtually the entire framework, incl. making sure no buffered content is left in SSLEngine and the likes.

Comment: ...something even funnier, there is no way to surely zero any memory in java besides DirectBuffer ones, since the GC is free to copy any memory as it sees fit. There are no requirements to zero after copy, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/), you can define a method like this:

```
public static boolean contains(final char[] array, final char[] target){
    return Chars.indexOf(array, target)>=0;
}
```

**Reference:**

[`Chars.indexOf(char[], char[])`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html#indexOf%28char%5B%5D%2C%20char%5B%5D%29)

---

And if you don't want to use Guava, here's the merged version of my method and Guava's:

```
public static boolean contains(final char[] array, final char[] target){
    // check that arrays are not null omitted
    if (target.length == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - target.length + 1; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < target.length; j++) {
        if (array[i + j] != target[j]) {
          continue outer;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String NOT_ALLOWED="...";

public boolean isPasswordOkay(char[] password){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(password);
    boolean ret = sb.indexOf(NOT_ALLOWED) != -1;
    sb.replace(0, sb.length(), " ");
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that sounds like what you want at http://www.coderanch.com/t/35439/Programming/Intersection-two-arrays - Intersection is the maths-y term for this kind of thing!

Comment: The intersection of `{'f','o','o'}` and `{'0','f','1,'9','c','o','$','s','o'}` is non-empty, but given the use-case here shouldn't mean the second term is an invalid password.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything that would do this. one option may be to use Apache Collections and use the [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) subarray methods to create sub-arrays and then compare on each one that you create, iterating through the original array.

Answer (score -1):

```
new String(password).matches(".*["+NOT_ALLOWED.replace(']','\\').replace("\\","\\\\\")+"].*");
```

Beware... you have to escape some of your not allowed characters, like `]` and `\`!

Comment: what is this for a requirement... why don't you just use some replace()es on your string... omg