# Best way/algorithm to find out if a string consists of only a given set of characters

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I was asked this in an interview,
If you to find out if a string consists of only a given set of characters. 
For example, let the set of strings be all strings over {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ie all "numeric" strings. Among this, if the set of strings over {3,8,5} are only valid ones, how do I check if the string consists of only valid characters.
Say:

```
Input 8888338385
     Output VALID
Input 887837348234 
Output : Invalid
```

The way that I suggested was brute force, that required checking every character in the given string against a list of invalid characters. If any one of the character was invalid, I'd skip checking all other characters and display the failure message.
However, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860336/fastest-algo-for-searching-set-of-characters-in-given-string), there may be better algorithms.
Please help.

Comment: The preferred solution was in c/c++ or java. Hence the tags.

Comment: Define `better`. Less memory consumption? Higher speed? More easy to understand and maintain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** Thanks to Luc Touraille for a vast improvement to the original algorithm.

Create an array `a[10]` of booleans. For each expected digit `e`, set `a[e] = true`.

Now for each digit `d` in your input, check if `a[d]` is true. If it's not, return false. If they all succeed, return true.

You can generalise this to all ASCII characters with a 256-element array.

If your input string is length N, your comparison string is length M, and the number of letters in your alphabet is A, then the complexity is O(N+M) (to scan your two strings) plus O(A) (to initialise the boolean array). So unless your string length is close to or greater than your alphabet size, this might not be optimal.

It's worth pointing out, with respect to Niklas Baumstark's excellent [performance comparison](http://ideone.com/oPKYq), that our two solutions are actually the same. The boolean array constructed here is *identical* to the transition table you'd build in a two-state [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) accepting  [c<sub>1</sub>c<sub>2</sub>...]*. I'd imagine the only difference is that Java's implementation, being much more general, carries a lot more overhead.

Comment: +1 good old lookup array.  Usually impractical for "real" programming tasks, but often helpful in "what's the fastest way" to do something very particular.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to start with the expected set? This way, you only need one array and you can stop iteration over the input string as soon as you find an invalid character. You would have at most M+N operations.

Comment: @Luc Yes, it would ;) Thanks.

Comment: I implemented a [benchmark to compare this to the regex-based  solution](http://ideone.com/oPKYq). To my surprise, Java's regex implementation actually seems to be very crappy, it is an order of magnitude slower than this solution! I would have expected the regex engine to also create a lookup table for such a large character class, but obviously it does not.

Answer (score 6):

**DISCLAIMER:** Against my assumptions, Java seems to [suck](http://ideone.com/oPKYq) at optimizing the regular expression used here, which results in unperformant code. Even Javascript's regular expressions seem to be faster than this. The benchmark also shows that Nick's solution is really fast.

This is definitely a task for a regular expression. In Java:

```
public boolean isValidString(String str) {
  return str.matches("[358]*");
}
```

This should be `O(n)` worst case, and it *can't* be better than that, because every character has to be looked at.

If performance is critical, you probably want to cache the pre-compiled pattern matcher:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Matcher {
  private Pattern pattern;

  public Matcher() {
    this.pattern = Pattern.compile("[358]*");
  }

  public isValid(String str) {
    return pattern.matcher(str).matches();
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt that also match "aa8" or just "aa"?

Comment: That's only true if the alphabet is of a small constant size, in which case the naive solution is also `O(N).`

Comment: @WeaselFox: What makes you think that? Regular expressions are compiled down to a very efficient internal representation. Even if he'd allow ~100 characters, this would probably still be faster then a solution written in Java code.

Comment: The *parsing* might be O(N), but you haven't factored in the cost of actually building the state machine ;) . Though if you're hardcoding the {3,5,8} set, I suppose we could just hardcode the state transition table and build a simplified state machine of our own.

Comment: Java regex is weird then. I'd have expected that to need ^ and $ to anchor it.

Comment: @awoodland: Actually it's the same way in many other languages (Python, Ruby for example). Usually there is a `search` method which behaves like you'd expect, while `match` or `matches` will check the whole string.

Comment: Also, while you might take this approach in production code, I wouldn't recommend giving this as your final answer in an interview...

Comment: @Nick Barnes: I made the assumption that OP wouldn't need many different patterns, so they can be pre-compiled.

Comment: @Nick Barnes: I actually didn't even read that this was an interview question... Still I think that the simplest solution is usually the best one and in that case it's even performant, so why not?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark - this is an interview question. If they are interested in the complexity of the solution, than youre solution will be `O(M*N)` where M is the size of the allowed set of characters and N is the length of the string. If the question is just to code it fast and efficient enough in a real world scenario, of course your solution is great.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark I suppose if you're reusing the same Pattern object over and over for different inputs, then your *amortised* runtime comes down to O(N), but regardless, it's not strictly linear.

Comment: @WeaselFox Where are you pulling O(M*N) from? Regex parsing can be linear. Do you know the details of Java's implementation?

Comment: @NickBarnes - well, maybe theres a data structure under the hood that sorts the characters in the set but I doubt it. in any case its not `O(N)` if the allowed set is not of constant length.

Comment: @WeaselFox: If you mean that the actual matching (without the state machine creation) will be `O(n*m)`, then you are plain wrong. The regex compiler applies a lot of optimizations. In this case the check probably boils down to something like `if (c == '3' || c == '5' ||  c == '8') return false;`, but if the list of allowed characters was longer (e.g. something like `\w`), a lookup table like would be created, so that the matching would be `O(n)` and already be optimized, native machine code.

Comment: @WeaselFox There are some costs in the compilation phase which are dependent on M. But in the parsing phase, a regex parser can process each of the N characters in constant time. Total cost is O(f(M)+N). (I don't know what f is).

Comment: I wonder if `if (c == '3' || c == '5' || c == '8') return false;` doesn't count as `O(m)` itself?

Comment: @visitor: It does not, because for larger `M`s this *will not happen!*

Comment: @WeaselFox: It seems like you were right. Java's regex implementation seems to be [very crappy](http://ideone.com/oPKYq). I find this both surprising and a bit hilarious, optimization is really not that hard for finite state machines like this. Even Javascript's regexes perform better in this example...

Answer (score 3):

You could use a map for each character in the allowed set (if the alphabet is of a limited range) and check directly for each character in the strings you check if its in the map. this way its only O(N) where N is the string length, and not O(N*M) where M is the set of allowed characters. If the alphabet is of large scale than another data structure could be used to store the allowed characters - sorted tree for example for complexity of O(N)logN.

Answer (score 3):

for c or c++, you can do something like this:

```
const char* haystack = "8888338385";
const char* filter = "385";

if (strlen(haystack) != strspn(haystack, filter))
{
  // oops - haystack contains more characters...
}
```

Equivalent `std::string` functions exist for c++ (`std::string::find_first_not_of`)

EDIT: I realise it's cheating, but there's nothing in the question which precludes this.

Answer (score -2):

i would first sort input and list of invalid letters, then you can always determine if the string is valid of not in linear time

Comment: Sorting the input makes it O(nlogn) in terms of input string length, while the simple solution is O(n).

Comment: do you mean the regex solution above? Its complexity is actually not O(n)! You have to compare each letter of the input with each letter of the invalid list, so it's actually O(m*n). By sorting you just need O(nlogn) + O(mlogm) + O(n+m)

Comment: @user1180720 The regex solution can easily be made O(n), with an appropriate implementation of regular expressions.  A "strict" regular expressions (without capture) define a DFA; this is actually what the traditional implementation of `egrep` used.

Comment: @James: I also would have expected Java to optimize this, but it seems to be [very crappy](http://ideone.com/oPKYq) at it! Do you know any resources on Sun's implementation?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark Not really.  Note that capture prevents actually using a DFA.  Although an optimized version could switch implementations, and use a DFA if there was no capture.  And for simple expressions like this one, there should be no backtracking in practice, and an NFA based implementation should still be O(n).

Comment: I am really confused a little. Are we talking about the complexity of the general problem of determining if any invalid character appears in an input string? Precompiling (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9113314/1180720) may help if the list of invalid characters is reused, but where was this mentioned in the original question?

Comment: 2) What should your DFA look like? Two states, Valid and Invalid? And three transitions from Valid to Invalid, listening to the events 3, 5, and 8? And a self-transition from Valid to Valid for every other characters? How does this work in a programming language? Three IFs and an ELSE right? And the DFA checks for every character in the input which transition to take? That's why the overall complexity if O(m*n), m being the length of the input string and o the length of the invalid-character list?